# Algebraic manipulation in Uniform convergence

Tags: real-analysis

i´m trying to prove that a sequence defined as $f_{n}(x):=\sqrt{x^{2}+\frac{|x|}{n}}$ uniformly converges in $\mathbb{R}$. i have that the $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_{n}(x)=|x|$ so i get that i need to solve the next expression $|\sqrt{x^{2}+\frac{|x|}{n}}-|x||$ but i dont know how to manipulate that expression, any help would be of great value.

Comment: $\sqrt a -b=\sqrt a -\sqrt {b^{2}}=\frac {a-b^{2}} {\sqrt a +\sqrt {b^{2}}}$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$x^2 + \frac{|x|}{n} < x^2 + 2 \frac{|x|}{n} + \frac{1}{n^2} = \left(|x| + \frac{1}{n} \right)^2$$

Comment: ohhhh so i would have $\sqrt{x^{2}+\frac{|x|}{n}}-|x| <||x||+\frac{1}{n}$

Comment: No - much better: $0 \leqslant \sqrt{x^2 +\frac{|x|}{n}} - |x| < \frac{1}{n}$

Comment: yes, sorry for my bad. í´m really thankful for your help. edit: Yes, i accidentally wrote the ||x|| after the < sign